# Laravel Gmail: Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8

Tags: php, laravel, email

Hey guys I am using laravel and trying to send mail from contact page.
It is working fine on local server, but when I am trying to test it on server it is giving me error with user credentials error.

Here is my .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp 
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com 
MAIL_PORT=587 
MAIL_USERNAME=app@gmail.com 
MAIL_PASSWORD=AppPassword 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: here is my .env file:
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=app@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=AppPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Comment: use MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail instead of smtp

Comment: its not working.

Comment: MAIL_DRIVER=mail also not working?

Comment: not its also not working. As i mentioned its properly working on localhost. could be there any php version problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just change your 'driver' => 'smtp', to 'driver' => 'sendmail' in env file.
Make sure allow less secure apps is ON in your google account settings.

Comment: Unexpectedly, It worked for me even today. When gmail is to discontinue "less secure apps" from May

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:
- Enable "Allow less secure apps" on your google account security policy.
- Restart your local servers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you enabled less secure app in security part of your google account. And better use

```
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my local server. I tried many options like turning on less secure apps and turned off 2-step verification but nothing seems worked for me.

So I found this solution, someone may get help with this solution.

You do not need to turn on less secure apps.

Turn on 2-step verification and then Create App Password by [clicking here](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords)

Select Others (custom name) and click generate.

Use that system generated password as your gmail password.

That's It!